# Testing Associations With RSpec in a Chess Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec-rails

I'm currently working with a small team on an open source Rails 4 chess application, and I'm trying to test out various possible piece moves in RSpec (including special cases such as en passant and castling).  A senior web developer suggested that I use a separate table to keep track of the moves taken in each game of chess.  After taking him up on his suggestion, I'm having trouble testing out valid moves, as shown in the error message below.  I suspect that it might be a problem with my associations, but the teammates that I was able to talk to about this were unsure about the cause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error message:

```
Failures:

1) PiecesController Action: pieces#update should create a move when a move is valid
 Failure/Error: @current_game ||= current_piece.game

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `game' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/pieces_controller.rb:36:in `current_game'
 # ./app/controllers/pieces_controller.rb:40:in `require_authorized_for_current_game'
 # ./spec/controllers/pieces_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test:

```
RSpec.describe PiecesController, type: :controller do
  describe "Action: pieces#update" do
    it "should create a move when a move is valid" do
      user_sign_in
      game = FactoryGirl.create(:game)
      # Test a white pawn's movement on its first turn:
      piece = FactoryGirl.create(:piece)
      move = FactoryGirl.create(:move)
      # Why can't I call game.id below?
      patch :update, :id => game.id, :pieces => {  }
      piece_params = { :x_position => piece.x_position, :y_position => piece.y_position, :type => "Pawn" }
      if piece.valid_move?(piece_params)
        ...
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def user_sign_in
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

Associations:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pieces
  has_many :moves, through: :pieces
  belongs_to :white_player, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :white_player_id
  belongs_to :black_player, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :black_player_id

  ...
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :moves

  def valid_move?(params)
    ...
  end

  ...
end

class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :piece
end
```

Factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    ...
  end

  factory :game do
    association :white_player, factory: :user
    association :black_player, factory: :user
    turn 1
  end

  factory :piece do
    association :game
    ...
  end

  # Set up an initially empty move, then adjust the values after checking that a piece can be moved:
  factory :move do
    association :piece
    ...
  end

end
```

The controller:

```
class PiecesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :require_authorized_for_current_game, only: [:update]
  before_action :require_authorized_for_current_piece, only: [:update]

  def update
    ...
  end

  ...

  private

  def current_piece
    @current_piece ||= Piece.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end

  ...

  def piece_params
    params.require(:piece).permit(:x_position, :y_position, :type, :captured)
  end

  def current_game
    @current_game ||= current_piece.game
  end

  def require_authorized_for_current_game
    if current_game.white_player != current_user && current_game.black_player != current_user
      render text: 'Unauthorized', status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems to me that you send `game.id` as id (`patch :update, :id => game.id, :pieces => {  }`) but in controller looking for `Piece` by this id (`@current_piece ||= Piece.find_by_id(params[:id])`). PS you can check logs or use [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) for debugging

Comment: I would model it as `POST /games/:game_id/moves` instead of `PATCH /peice/:id`. You are creating a move in a game - the fact that it moves the piece is a side effect.

Comment: @gotva  You're right, I switched out the game.id to piece.id.  Thanks for the quick help.